# Dapper convert DbNull to empty string

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dapper, sqlcommand

I am refactoring some code that used reflection to map a SqlCommand to a model. The new code uses the Dapper framework and works perfectly fine:

```vb
    Public Shared Function GetModel(Of T As New)(cmd As SqlCommand) As T
        Try

            Dim params = GetParametersDictionary(cmd)
            Dim result As Object

            Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
                result = conn.Query(Of T)(cmd.CommandText, params).FirstOrDefault()
            End Using

            Return result

        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorsLogger.LogException(ex)
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function
```

However in the old code I had an edge case for string properties and DbNull values. Something like:

```vb
    If IsTypeOfString(prop) AndAlso IsDbNull(value) Then
        prop.SetValue(obj, "")
    End If
```

The new code does not convert DbNull (NULL) values to an empty string. Instead it leaves the value just not set aka Nothing, breaking some code elsewhere.

So my question is how to change this function to convert NULL values to an empty string? Preferably without reflection.

Things tried / considered / constraints:

- Custom Dapper SqlMapper: Does not work when values are NULL.
- Custom model mapper: Cannot create a custom model mapper for every model type.
- Init strings as "" in class constructor: Cannot guaranty that every string property is correctly initialized with "".
- Cannot change the queries or model classes (at least for now).

Comment: How about, in the `select` clause of the SQL using `Coalesce(column, '') as column` and not deal with this generically at all. (IMHO it is odd to have a model with non-nullable properties when there are nulls in the DB.)

Comment: Totally agreed. Unfortunately I have to deal with this old code and have no access to the models, or the queries. Updated the question to add this constraint.

Comment: I never worked with dapper, but you could probably create a type handler for strings. Here is an example of a type handler not doing quite what you need, but you could adapt it: [Converting varchar to IHtmlString](https://riptutorial.com/dapper/example/11/converting-varchar-to-ihtmlstring).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Unfortunately due to how dapper works the CustomTypeHandler (aka Dapper SqlMapper) is not called for NULL values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper is of the opinion that `null` and `""` are different things, and actively tries not to conflate the two. You could post-process the results, perhaps.

Comment: Ok. It is going to be Post-processing... For now at least. I am gonna log/find the code that depends on this empty-string-code, and fix it there.

Comment: @Vincent you could also just have `public string Whatever {get;set;} = "";` so that it is an empty string by default?